# Do ability modifiers grant a bonus to your saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

Okay, so here are the circumstances. For the *Rogue* class in the PHB, p. 95, *Dexterity* and *Intelligence* are listed under **Proficiencies** > **Saving Throws**.
Does this mean I am granted the proficiency bonus in addition to my DEX and INT modifiers towards those saving throws?

Also are all of your saving throws granted bonuses from ability modifiers? 
Say I'm not proficient in CHA saving throws - do I still get the +1 from having 12 CHA?

Comment: before I adjusted your question, you asked whether the +2 modifier from 12 CHA would still get added - are you aware that, with 12 CHA, your modifier is only +1? The *PHB* has a list of modifiers according to ability scores, or you simply subtract 10 from your score and halve it (rounding down).

Comment: Does this differ from all the similar questions that have been asked and closed? A cursory search reveals [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92800/how-do-you-add-the-proficiency-bonus-to-your-saving-throws-and-skills), among many others, to say nothing of the PHB, starter set, etc.

Comment: @lunatamis IMO it is close but not a duplicate of that or any other question I can find. We also don't close questions if their answers can be found in the books. Our job is often to create answers using those references and point people to the books.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your saving throw modifiers are calculated from the corresponding ability score and, if you are proficient in a particular save, your proficiency bonus.

So, assuming that you're for example a level 1 *Half-Orc* *Barbarian* (saving throw proficiencies: STR, CON) with the following stats (point buy):

- STR: 16 (+3)
- DEX: 14 (+2)
- CON: 16 (+3)
- INT: 8  (-1)
- WIS: 10 (0)
- CHA: 8  (-1)

You would have the following saving throw modifiers

- STR: +5
- DEX: +2
- CON: +5
- INT: -1
- WIS: +0
- CHA: -1

See also PHB, p. 179, *Saving Throws*.